# Error with Microsoft SQL Server Analysis

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer Version and SQl Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017. When I tried to create an OLAP cube using Visual Studio, I failed to deploy the project receiving following error: 'The project could not be deployed to the 'localhost' server because of the following connectivity problems :A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.' I checked whether the connection with SSAS is possible via SQL Server Management Studio, however it failed too with the error 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2383'.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the SSAs service running on your local machine?